# Why can I not use alias name for FUNC in JPQL

Tags: jpql, toplink

I have a JPQL Query something like

```
select col1,col2, FUNC('CONCAT',FUNC('CONCAT',col3,'-'), col4) as aliascolName.
```

I need to provide an alias name for my FUNC call as I need to use this concatenated result for providing filtering option from UI and also in ORDER BY Clause.

I am using JPA2.0 with TOPLINK12.1.2